# Why is my variable not being read inside brackets in a select statement xsl

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I'm not sure why my queryString variable not being read in totalRecords's select statement. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    
        <xsl:variable name="carMake">
            <xsl:value-of select="//input_payload/carMake"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        
        <xsl:variable name="queryString">Sold='False'</xsl:variable>
  {
    carMake: <xsl:value-of select="$carMake"/>,
   querystring: <xsl:value-of select="$queryString"/>,
   "totalRecords": <xsl:value-of select="count(//responseAfterTransform[$queryString])"/>,
   
   }
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT 3 has `xsl:evaluate` as well as shadow attributes and static parameters and higher order functions to allow some of the stuff you expect there to work to be implemented; for earlier versions you would need to look into proprietary extensions or XSLT -> XSLT transformation.

Comment: *"What am I missing..."* You are missing the difference between `responseAfterTransform[bold='False']` and `responseAfterTransform["bold='False'"]` - IOW, the difference between an *expression* (which is apparently what you want) and a *string* (which is what you have).

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3 example showing the use of a shadow attribute with a static parameter or of `xsl:evaluate` to construct a predicate expression from a string:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 2</name>
    <category>bar</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 3</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 4</name>
    <category>baz</category>
  </item>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="predicate" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'category = ''foo'''"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <shadow-attribute-example>
      <xsl:sequence _select="//item[{$predicate}]"/>
    </shadow-attribute-example>
    <evaluate-example>
      <xsl:evaluate xpath="'//item[' || $predicate || ']'" context-item="."/>
    </evaluate-example>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jypqQ9e gives e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shadow-attribute-example>
   <item>
      <name>item 1</name>
      <category>foo</category>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>item 3</name>
      <category>foo</category>
   </item>
</shadow-attribute-example>
<evaluate-example>
   <item>
      <name>item 1</name>
      <category>foo</category>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>item 3</name>
      <category>foo</category>
   </item>
</evaluate-example>
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can achieve the same result using version 1 or 2? I've been trying to find an extension to make this possible in v1 or v2 but have not been sucessful

Comment: @JCastillo, you will need to tell us which XSLT processor you normally use. Most XSLT 2 users tend to use some version of Saxon and Saxon since 2017 supports XSLT 3, although `xsl:evaluate` support in the open-source HE edition I think was only introduced in Saxon 10. Shadow attributes/static params should work in 9.8 or 9.9 as well. SaxonJS 2 also support them as well as `xsl:evaluate`. Proprietary extension for XSLT 1 or 2 processors depend on the particular processor and/or its API.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to find an extension to make this possible in v1 or v2 but have not been sucessful

In *some* XSLT 1.0 processors (e.g. `libxslt` or `Xalan`) you can use the EXSLT [dyn:evaluate()](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html) extension function - for example:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 2</name>
    <category>bar</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 3</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
    <item>
    <name>item 4</name>
    <category>baz</category>
  </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="predicate">category="foo"</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="item[dyn:evaluate($predicate)]" />
    </output>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>item 3</name>
    <category>foo</category>
  </item>
</output>
```

Not sure why you need this at all. In your example, the predicate is a *variable* hard-coded into the stylesheet, not a *parameter* that can be supplied dynamically during runtime. In these circumstances, you could simply hard-code the predicate directly into the `select` expression, without going through a string first.